# Sound of running water behind walls upstairs and downstairs

Tags: water, leak

I woke up this morning to the sound of water running behind my walls. We live in a townhouse and share walls with 3 other owners. I've checked my toilet tanks in all bathroom to be sure the valve is not open, and all seems fine. I've asked one neighbor to check and she said all good on her side. Another neighbor is out of town, and the 3rd neighbor just moved in a few months ago whom I've not yet met. I will ask them tomorrow to check their toilet tank flush valve. Oddly enough earlier today I could hear a neighbor flushed their toilet, and the water running thru the walls stopped for a brief second. Am I onto something or just wishful thinking?  I looked at my ceiling and the walls and no sign of leakage. Once I've contacted all my neighbors, and the noise continues, I will have my plumber come in and see what the problem is. Any other suggestions are welcome. Thank you.

Comment: Is there snow & ice on the roof? Ice dams can cause water in the walls, which you may hear long before you see it. For that matter, is the wall or walls you hear water in an exterior wall or an interior wall? Please [edit] the question to add these details.

Comment: Do you have the type of toilet that has a flush valve or a standard tank? If its the former then its possible the neighbor has a stuck valve on their toilet. These valves require greater pressure than tank toilets and in a residential setup could cease leaking momentarily  when another valve is flushed. Greatest danger in this scenario is a larger water bill that month.